# Is OpenJDK6 still supported?

Tags: java

I use OpenJDK6, but is in necessary to update to OpenJDK7?

It seems that Oracle has dropped support for Java 6...

I read here that Red Hat will be providing support for OpenJDK6: http://java.about.com/b/2013/03/07/red-hat-assumes-leadership-of-openjdk-6.htm

Does that mean that Ubuntu will continue to deliver security updates and bugfixes to OpenJDK6?

Or do I have to update...

I'm using the current LTS release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no indication that Ubuntu has stopped providing support and backport updates for JDK6.

As of March 5 2013, Ubuntu was still sending out [security notifications](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-1755-1/), along with providing the necessary patches for vulnerabilities found in Open JDK6.

While Oracle has ended support for public updates, the Open JDK6-dev team [has stated](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk6-dev/2013-March/002890.html):

> "Oracle ended public updates of JDK6 at the end of last month.  Many
>   people seem to have concluded that the OpenJDK6 project will therefore
>   end at the same time.  This is incorrect: OpenJDK6 will continue, but
>   will be maintained by the community outside Oracle."
>
> - What about security updates?
>
> "We'll back-port them as they arrive and commit them to OpenJDK 6.
>   However, there may be some delay because of the effort and testing
>   that back-porting requires.  Therefore, ***if you want the most secure
>   and up-to-date version of OpenJDK, you should update to OpenJDK 7.
>   We'll also fix any security bugs that are found in OpenJDK 6 alone,
>   but again there may be some delay.***"

At this time, security updates will be backported to JDK6 as long as there is a community to support it. Presumably, these will be rolled into Debian, and down to Ubuntu.

You can read the entire thread in the March 2013 jdk6-dev mail archives under the title: [The future of OpenJDK6](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk6-dev/2013-March/thread.html#2890).

Answer (score 1):

OpenJDK6 is not supported by ubuntu any longer
if you installed it when upgrading ubuntu, OpenJDK6 will be upgraded to 7
try to install it from ppa or source code
why don't you install OpenJDK7? it has what ever you need to run programs that has written in java6